# Run 2 commands when starting windows terminal

Tags: windows-terminal

What I want to do is connect to my VPN via rasdial and ssh into my machine when I open a Windows Terminal window, but I can't figure out how to do both on startup.

I created a new profile, but in the 'commandline' section I can't run more than one command as && or ; don't seem to work.

Another issue I have is that when I run the rasdial command on startup the window closes immediately.

The syntax in the json file is as follows:
`"commandline": "command"`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&&` and `;` are shell interpreter features, so just call a shell interpreter to make them work:

```
"command": "cmd /c rasdial this && ssh that"
```

Should also work with other shells, though PowerShell seems to need [a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18455047/49849) of obscure options:

```
"command": "powershell -NoProfile -Command \"rasdial this && ssh that\""
```